# Behavior of singularity of $e^{-z^2}$ at infinite

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

The function
$$f(z)=e^{-z^2}$$
doesn't have any singularity in the finite plane. For singularity at the infinite plane
$$g(z)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=e^{-1/z^2}$$
This function has singular behavior at $z=0$. To know what kind of singularity, I have to find the Laurent series. But that's a nontrivial task, For it, we need to find the coefficients:
$$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{k+1}} d\zeta$$
I'm not sure, If we can simply use $e^{-z}$ with $z\rightarrow 1/z^2$. Please help me with this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the Laurent series from the Taylor series for $\mathrm{e}^u$ and then set $u = -1/z^2$?  You know that Laurent series are [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Uniqueness), so if you find one, you've found it.

Comment: @EricTowers So can I always do that? I mean, Suppose I know the expansion of $f(z)$ and I want to know the expansion of $g(f(z))$. Can I put the series expansion of $f$ in $g$ to find the series expansion of $g(z)$?

Comment: If, after you compute the composition of series, what you have is a Laurent series, then yes.  This need not always happen.  A simple example is when the series for $f$ produces values that are not in the annulus of convergence of the series for $g$.  (This can't happen in the Question because the exponential function is entire.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Taylor series for $e^z = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ where $z = - \frac{1}{w^2}$ and it becomes obvious that you have an essential singularity.